# Spectrogram app for the Mac

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, audio

Where do I find a real time spectrogram analysis application for the Mac?  Freeware or Shareware if possible.

Answer (score 2):

[Spectrogram](http://downloads.zdnet.com/abstract.aspx?docid=423329) is a free real-time spectrum analyzer VST plug-in for Macintosh. The spectrum may be shown in 4 different modes: "Spectrograph view" - "Waterfall view/ 3D" - "Spectrogram view" - "Power view" . Settings include: input choice (mono/stereo), FFT Size choice (1024/4096), magnitude and scroll/frame speed.

Answer (score 1):

[AudioXplorer](http://www.arizona-software.ch/audioxplorer/) is pretty good, [open source](https://github.com/johndpope/AudioXplorer) (BSD license), and it can do both real-time and file analysis.  It shows an oscilloscope, spectrum, and spectrogram/sonogram.

[image: screenshot]

One flaw is that the frequency axis and spectrum level are both linear instead of being log-scaled frequency and dB, and I don't see an option to change that.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the best as of 2023: https://friture.org/